# when quering customers from QBO i get duplicate customers

Tags: quickbooks-online

I seem to keep getting duplicates back when I query quickbooks online via the customer query.  below is my code and I am wondering why i get the same customer back multiple times.  I am using the paging feature to avoid timeouts.

```
        Dim tCust As New List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer)

        Dim qcust As New CustomerQuery
        qcust.IncludeJobs = False
        qcust.LastUpdatedTime = FromDate
        qcust.PageNumber = 1
        qcust.ResultsPerPage = 10

        Dim customers As IEnumerable(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer) = qcust.ExecuteQuery(Of Customer)(GetServiceContext)
        While customers.Count > 0
            tCust.AddRange(customers)
            customers = qcust.ExecuteQuery(Of Customer)(GetServiceContext)
            qcust.PageNumber += 1
        End While
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not incrementing the page number in the correct place, so you are executing two requests for PageNum=1 and ResultsPerPage=10.

The page number should be incremented in the loop as follows:

```
Dim tCust As New List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer)()

Dim qcust As New CustomerQuery()
qcust.IncludeJobs = False
qcust.LastUpdatedTime = New DateTime(2013, 1, 1)
qcust.PageNumber = 1
qcust.ResultsPerPage = 10

Dim customers As IEnumerable(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer) = qcust.ExecuteQuery(Of Customer)(context)
While customers.Any()
    tCust.AddRange(customers)
    If customers.Count() < qcust.ResultsPerPage Then Exit While
    qcust.PageNumber += 1
    customers = qcust.ExecuteQuery(Of Customer)(context)
End While
```